# How to setup AWS cloud watch for RAM and EBS capacity usages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch

I wonder, how to setup `AWS cloud watch` for `RAM and EBS capacity` usages?

As I have not seen any metrics for the same.

I have seen some python scripts which need to setup as CRON, is that safe in respect to GDPR?

> PS
>   I am successfully able to setup `AWS cloud watch` for CPU usages.

Comment: The answer from John is best, but there are older [scripts from Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) that still work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install the CloudWatch Agent in your instance. Both Linux and Windows is supported.

This link will provide details:

[Collect Metrics from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @john-hanley I got the answer. I see there so many metrics available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CW_Support_For_AWS.html#metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent